# Codeigniter: write_file() returns false

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, writefile

```
public function ExportCSV()
{
    // THIS PART IS WORKING
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $delimiter = ',';
    $newline = "\n";
    $enclosure = '"';
    $filename = "tamp.csv";
    $query = "SELECT politician.id, politician.ident, party.abbr, politician.id_image, politician.name, politician.surname, politician.personal_birth, politician.home_city, politician.political_function  
      FROM politician 
      INNER JOIN party 
      WHERE party.id = politician.id_party 
      LIMIT 10000";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline, $enclosure);

    // data IS CORRECT
    // THIS PART NOT WORKING: write_file() returns false
    if ( ! write_file(APPPATH."/assets/media/upload/tamp.csv", $data, 'r+'))
    {
        echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'File written!';
    }
}
```

The variable `$data` contains the correct output but the `write_file()` returns `false`.

The directory `/assets/` is in the main directory of the codeigniter project.

My questions are:

- Is this function returning false because I don't have the permission to write in this directory?

  - If yes, what should I do?
- In which directory should I write this file as I would like it public?

Comment: What if you just try...write_file("./assets/media/upload/tamp.csv", $data, 'r+') with the assets folder direct off your document root and not under your APPPATH.

Comment: First off all assets should be out side of application folder. Then try `FCPATH . "assets/media/upload/tamp.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

When creating a file with write_file make sure your folder/directory is there where you would like to create file

Then I would recommend using FCPATH
     $data = "Some file data";

```
 if (write_file(FCPATH . '/document/text.txt', $data) == FALSE)
 {
     echo 'Unable to write the file';

 } else {
     echo 'File written!';                           
 }
```

My directory
     application

```
 document

 system

 index.php
```